# Sequilize/express and AWS RDS too many connections

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js, pm2

Building an API backend using Node/Express/Sequelize. Running pm2 on 2 quad core EC2 instances (8 clusters) and Aurora RDS with 3,000 connections available. Currently running Sequelize 5. Every few days of testing I get "too many connections" error from mysql.

This is for a new job. I've tried multiple pool configurations but the result is the same.

````
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "pool": {
        "max": 30,
        "min": 5,
        "idle": 10000,
        "acquire": 60000
    }
} ```

Expected Sequelize to reuse or close connections.
````

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest somethings which may help you to resolve this issue.

1) Just increase the connection pool because you have enough server specs.

2) Decrease time of acquire to 30000 rather than 60000 so it will take much time to start connecting again and avoid to lost any data or problem to the user of the system.

3) Just check with "top" server logs that how much connection are created and make sure idle connections should be removed.